# SCIM1.1 : conflicts in schemas attribute and user's attribute

Tags: rest, scim

I am trying to get data from salesforce using SCIM1.1 endpoints. When I get data for a user using "/Users/id" endpoint it returns me all attribute and their value for user.
In these attributes I get one attribute name "alias" Ex. "alias": "BBuru".
But when I get schema of salesforce using "/Schemas" endpoint it gives all other attributes containing core as well as extended schema except "alias".

As I get alias in user object and not present in schema object It causes issue to map values from user object to schema attribute.

So can you clarify about "Why alias is returned for get Users but not returned in Schemas?